Determining origin of SSH traffic being blocked
I have a simple SSH jump host sitting at a remote site. I could connect without issue for the first two weeks. But now initiating a session seems to fail unless I use a proxy.
jump host ------- ISP A -------------------------- ISP B ---------- my workstation
Port 55555 is properly forwarded through ISP A. The connection simply times out.
ssh -vvv -p 55555 XX.XX.XX.XX
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XX.XX.XX.XX is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/mansomean/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/mansomean/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 55555.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address XX.XX.XX.XX port 55555: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host XX.XX.XX.XX port 55555: Connection timed out

And if I push it over a VPN, for example, the connection is immediately accepted. It is only accepted so long as does not originate from my public IP at ISP B. Is there a way I can ascertain whether ISP B (or A) might be blocking this traffic? And why no connectivity issue in the first two weeks?

The first step would be trying to figure out whether the traffic actually still gets there. Use tcpdump -v host XX.XX.XX.XX on the server  ... is the jump host solely maintained by you? Is it behind a firewall of sorts, if it is, can you configure it? ...

I think your next step would be traceroute -T -p 55555 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. This runs a TCP SYN traceroute against the destination port. It may work as long as the routers in the path do not block RST packets originating from themselves.

traceroute with -T -p switches produces 30 hops of * * *.

I deployed and maintain the jump host. The equipment with ISP A only exposes a means of forwarding ports and viewing IPv4 addresses of attached devices, it is very restrictive. I can view sshd journalctl logs which reveals my entry from proxy networks, but attempts to enter directly from my ISP B leased address do not appear in the logs.

If all you get is "* * *", then that points to issues from the very first hop.

I've taken some time to monitor connections to get a better picture of what's going on. My ISP (ISP B) leases a new IP address every 12-24 hours (only the last octet changes).
Only one of the addresses in this rotation appears to be blocked:

Only one of the addresses in this rotation appears to be blocked:
Login okay 12/9 from 66.152.75.38
Login okay 12/10 from 66.152.75.38
Not okay 12/14 from 66.152.75.32
Login okay 12/14 from 66.152.75.31
Not okay 12/15 from 66.152.75.32
Login okay 12/16 from 66.152.75.38
Login okay 12/17 from 66.152.75.35
Login okay 12/18 from 66.152.75.27

My working theory is that I had started transferring large volumes of data from my workstation to the remote site while on the address ending in .32 and the overzealous ISP A identified that as "malicious traffic" thus blocking that address.
I have not transmitted large amounts of data since then, and no new IP addresses appear to have been blocked.
Maybe if I transferred over port 443 instead it would look more innocent and not get blocked?
